# Getting a job status update with R

Tags: r

I have a rather simple question that I can't seem to find an answer for.
I essentially want to know if there is code that provide a status for the code we are running.  As an example, I am running code that usually takes time and would like to know if the job is 25%-50%-75% complete.  This is the kind of features we get with Software from large companies ($$).
Does anyone use anything when working with R?
I use Rstudio if this is pertinent.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "provide a status for the code we are running"? Do you mean to say that you want to know how close the computations themselves are to being complete?

Comment: Do you mean something like a [progress bar](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/r-monitor-function-progress-with-a-progress-bar/)?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know if the job has processed 80% of the records for instance.  A sort of indicator of the % completeness of the job.

Comment: @MauritsEvers a progress bar with be ideal but I doubt it can be done with R.  Anything to allow to know how close/far my code will finish running.  I remember having something like this with SPSS-Modeler from IBM.

Comment: @stuski Yes it can be done! See the link I give. You don't even need an additional library; see `?txtProgressBar`.

Comment: @stuski Also see [`pbapply`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/pbapply/index.html) for a progress bar with vectorised operations (from the `*apply` family).

Comment: @MauritsEvers this is great!!  I appreciate your input.  The example with the endless loop issue is very close to my situation.

Comment: No problem at all. I remember being amazed when I found out about `txtProgressBar` which had been there all along:-)